# como retorno un valor atreves de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buenas gente estoy enviando unos valores atraves de un procedimiento almacenado para obtener un estado, mi problema es que independiente de la validación en el IF del procedimiento siempre me retorna  1 siendo que tengo validado si son diferentes del procedimiento almacenado que desarrolle para mi sistema
¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema que tengo?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidaNC]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
   @Num_Impreso int
 , @Id_Doc as uniqueidentifier
 , @id_Doc2 as uniqueidentifier
 , @status INT OUTPUT
 
 AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

Declare @cod_empresa1 as uniqueidentifier
Declare @cod_empresa2 as uniqueidentifier


Select  Cod_Empresa as codigo
into #Temp1
from Ges_NcvCabecera
where Cod_Tienda = @Id_Doc 

select @Cod_empresa1 = codigo
from #Temp1

drop table #Temp1

select Cod_Empresa as codigo
into #Temp2
from Ges_NcvCabecera 
where Cod_Cliente = @id_Doc2 and Nro_Impreso = @Num_Impreso

select @Cod_empresa2 = codigo
from #Temp2

drop table #Temp2

IF @cod_empresa1 <> @cod_empresa2
BEGIN 
Rollback Transaction
SET @status = 0
Return 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
SET @status = 1
Return 1
END

End
```

Comment: podrías mostrar como consumes el stored procedure?, adicional, ya consideraste en hacerlo por medio de una función tipo escalar, en vez de por un stored procedure? (solo considera usar variables tipo tabla en vez de tablas temporales)

Comment: Sin ver los datos que hay en las tablas, al menos para un caso de ejemplo, no hay como analizar el problema, menos responder a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está relacionado con asignar un valor a la variable de salida `@status`.

En lugar de usar el `Return` dentro del bloque `IF`, debes asignar directamente el valor a la variable `@status` y luego finalizar el procedimiento almacenado con `RETURN` sin ningún valor.

Por ejemplo, así:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidaNC]
   @Num_Impreso int
 , @Id_Doc as uniqueidentifier
 , @id_Doc2 as uniqueidentifier
 , @status INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   Declare @cod_empresa1 as uniqueidentifier
   Declare @cod_empresa2 as uniqueidentifier

   Select  Cod_Empresa as codigo
   into #Temp1
   from Ges_NcvCabecera
   where Cod_Tienda = @Id_Doc 

   select @Cod_empresa1 = codigo
   from #Temp1

   drop table #Temp1

   select Cod_Empresa as codigo
   into #Temp2
   from Ges_NcvCabecera 
   where Cod_Cliente = @id_Doc2 and Nro_Impreso = @Num_Impreso

   select @Cod_empresa2 = codigo
   from #Temp2

   drop table #Temp2

   IF @cod_empresa1 <> @cod_empresa2
   BEGIN 
      Rollback Transaction
      SET @status = 0
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN 
      SET @status = 1
   END

   RETURN;
END
```

Comment: No, el valor de `@status` no va a ser diferente si el `return` lo pones más abajo.

Answer (score 2):

Pueden existir diversas razones para que obtengas el resultado incorrecto. Si uno de los valores no regresa filas, entonces obtendrías un nulo y la comparación no regresaría verdadero. Otra opción es que no estés recuperando el valor de forma adecuada.

Empecemos por como debes recuperar el valor que se obtiene de este procedimiento. El valor que regresa `RETURN` debe ser utilizado únicamente para indicar errores o advertencias durante la ejecución del procedimiento, no para la lógica de negocio. Por lo tanto, no lo necesitamos para este procedimiento. Lo que vas a usar es el parámetro de salida, esto lo podemos llamar así.

```
DECLARE @status INT;

EXEC [dbo].[ValidaNC]
   @Num_Impreso = @ValorParametro1
 , @Id_Doc = @ValorParametro2
 , @id_Doc2 = @ValorParametro3
 , @status = @status OUTPUT;

SELECT @status;
```

Pero si el problema son los valores que estás comparando, lo ideal sería simplificar el procedimiento para ver que el código de la empresa coincida o no. Para esto, no necesitamos tablas temporales o inclusive variables, solo hace falta operadores de conjuntos.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidaNC]
   @Num_Impreso int 
 , @Id_Doc      uniqueidentifier 
 , @id_Doc2     uniqueidentifier 
, @status       INT OUTPUT 
AS

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Si existe alguna diferencia, regresamos un estatus 0
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT Cod_Empresa 
    FROM   Ges_NcvCabecera
    WHERE  Cod_Tienda = @Id_Doc 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Cod_Empresa
    FROM   Ges_NcvCabecera 
    WHERE  Cod_Cliente = @id_Doc2 
    AND    Nro_Impreso = @Num_Impreso
)
    SET @status = 0;
ELSE 
    SET @status = 1;

RETURN;

GO
```